# Laravel 5.1 with Foundation-apps intergration

Tags: laravel-5.1, zurb-foundation-apps

Id like to use foundation-apps into my laravel 5.1 app .Foundation-apps has being successfully installed into node_modules folder using 'npm' ,how would I intergrate foundation apps into elixir module (gulp.js) file .

Answer (score 1):

maybe this post on laracasts forum can help you

[Foundation 5 and Laravel 5 Elixir](https://goo.gl/LRTaae)

or this answer

[Foundation with Laravel and Elixir](http://goo.gl/OGeuGZ)

Comment: Nice answer ,however both links demonstrate use of foundation-sites , but id like to know use with foundation-apps just as my question tag goes , so am not accepting this answer yet