# Not getting Foundation's Javascript elements to work (with Laravel and Elixir)

Tags: javascript, laravel, zurb-foundation

I've set up Foundation for my Laravel site according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087197/609778). It works great but I can't seem to get my javascript elements to work. ([see live example](http://104.131.86.114/testpage)).

I pull in the scripts at the bottom of the page (they link properly and look ok):

```
  <script src="http://104.131.86.114/js/main.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://104.131.86.114/js/dependencies.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
```

This is how I compile them (my gulpfile):

```
// Compile JavaScript
mix.browserify('main.js');

mix.scripts(
    ['vendor/modernizr.js', 'vendor/jquery.js', 'foundation.js'], // Source files. You can also selective choose only some components
    'public/js/dependencies.js', // Destination file
    'vendor/bower_components/foundation/js/' // Source files base directory
);
```

But simple things like an accordeon menu, or a slider won't work properly

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="200">
  <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

It's very likely something simple, so I really appreciate you taking your time.

**edit:**
The gulpfile above pulls in foundation.js from foundation 5. Foundation 6 now resides in vendor/bower-components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js. I updated my gulpfile to:

```
mix.scripts(
    ['modernizr/modernizr.js', 'jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js'], // Source files. You can also selective choose only some components
    'public/js/dependencies.js', // Destination file
    'vendor/bower_components/' // Source files base directory
);
```

Which improves the JavaScript functionality a bit, but still won't show the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vendor/bower_components/foundation` is where Foundation 5 stored all its resources. Foundation 6 uses the folder `vendor/bower_components/foundation-sites`.

Updating the `gulpfile.js` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087197/609778) to foundation 6:

```
elixir(function(mix) {

// Compile CSS
mix.sass(
    'app.scss', // Source files
    'public/css', // Destination folder
    {includePaths: ['vendor/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss']}
);

// Compile JavaScript
mix.scripts(
    ['modernizr/modernizr.js', 'jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js'], // Source files. You can also selective choose only some components
    'public/js/dependencies.js', // Destination file
    'vendor/bower_components/' // Source files base directory
    );
});
```

Also, update your `app.scss` to:

```
@import "settings";

// Include all foundation
@import "foundation";
@include foundation-everything;
```

Importing normalize is no longer neccesary.